# Syntax error while creating Materialized View in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, version, syntax-error, materialized-views

Syntax error while creating materialized view in MySQL:

Tried to create the mview as below:

```
 create materialized view test.dept10
 as
 select * from test.employees
 where deptno=10;

**ERROR 1064 (42000):** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'materialized view test.dept10
```

Comment: you should have checked the manual before posting. This is not supported by MySQL. That syntax *only* works for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the box MySQL doesn't do materialized views.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because MySQL does not have materialized views.
Read [this article](http://fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) for which I post the first part:

> A Materialized View (MV) is the pre-calculated (materialized) result
>   of a query. Unlike a simple VIEW the result of a Materialized View is
>   stored somewhere, generally in a table. Materialized Views are used
>   when immediate response is needed and the query where the Materialized
>   View bases on would take to long to produce a result. Materialized
>   Views have to be refreshed once in a while. It depends on the
>   requirements how often a Materialized View is refreshed and how actual
>   its content is. Basically a Materialized View can be refreshed
>   immediately or deferred, it can be refreshed fully or to a certain
>   point in time. MySQL does not provide Materialized Views by itself.
>   But it is easy to build Materialized Views yourself.

In [MySql page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) you can find other examples on how achieve your goal.

Comment: @user1041661: you're welcome. As you're new here, I would remember you  that you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it solved or helped to solve your problem.